# Can't get node's text with XPATH from my XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Hey everybody thanks for your time, I'm trying to parse a big XML file (pic bellow) and to get the text of specific nodes using XPATH expression in PHP.

Here is my php :

```
<?php
echo "[Generation Starts !]\n";
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);



if (file_exists('../source/particuliers/arborescence.xml')) {


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('../source/particuliers/arborescence.xml'));

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('dc', 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');

$themes = $xml->xpath("/Arborescence/Item[@type='Theme']/Titre/text()");

var_dump($themes);





$JSON = json_encode($themes, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

file_put_contents('testing.json', $JSON);

echo "[Generation Done !]\n";

} else {

  echo "File wasn't found\n";

}
```

I won't put the whole XML file here as it is way too big but here is a pic so you see the structure

[image: xml file]

Using this XPATH expression `/Arborescence/Item[@type='Theme']/Titre/text()` I expected to get text from my nodes but I only have an empty array with the right number of elements in it but all empty.

Anything I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Since `Item[@type='Theme']` matches many items you are most likely getting NodeList (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), not an empty array - pls check returned type. In such a case you need to traverse items. If you want to get a single item only, use unique item selector e.g. `Item[@ID='19809']` to test whether XPath actually works. Also you may need to cast to `(string)` returned results otherwise XPath may return node object rather than a value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this inisght, I gonna check this properly thanks

Comment: Okay indeed after a simple :

foreach ($themes as $key => $value) {
  echo (string)$value;
}

I can see my texts, sorry for the newbee question :€

Answer (score 0):

The result of `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` is always an array of SimpleXMLElement objects (or false for an invalid expression). SimpleXMLElement object represent element nodes, but the extension does some magic for text nodes and attributes.

Stripping down the code from the question into an example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<Arborescence>
  <Item type="Theme">
    <Titre>Loisirs</Titre>
  </Item>
</Arborescence>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$themes = $xml->xpath("/Arborescence/Item[@type='Theme']/Titre/text()");

var_dump($themes);
```

Output:

```
array(1) { 
  [0]=> 
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { 
    [0]=> 
    string(7) "Loisirs"
  }
}
```

The result is an array with a single SimpleXMLElement that contains the text. You can use `array_map()` to cast all returned objects to strings.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$themes = array_map(
    function(SimpleXMLElement $element) {
        return (string)$element;
    },
    $xml->xpath("/Arborescence/Item[@type='Theme']/Titre/text()")
);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> 
  string(7) "Loisirs" 
}
```